# Raise error after reload android app on React-native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

When I run the app via "expo run:android" the app starts, but if I close the app in the emulator and try to run it again, I get 2 errors:

```
Screen native module hasn't been linked. Please check the react-native-screens README for more details
```

and

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.
```

Is this normal behavior or am I missing something?

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "mwproductivity",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```